# Identify a 70's board game involving finding objects a house using cards

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

I have this 70's game and it is missing parts. Can anyone help me identify this game so I can complete this? I think it is European (maybe Swiss), but I don't have any indication of its name written on the board or cards. It consists of finding objects in the house using the cards. Some of the parts of the house in the picture are missing.

Comment: I've cleaned up this question a little bit so that the grammar is improved. If I misunderstood your question, please feel free to undo my changes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Ravensburger children's game, called Spielhaus in German, and [Race to the Roof](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10613/race-roof) in English. The art is different though, it looks like yours is a [Janosch version](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/164328/otto-maier-janosch-design-edition).